# Show $\lnot(p\land q) \equiv \lnot p \lor\lnot q$

Tags: logic, proof-verification

Show  $\lnot(p\land q) \equiv \lnot p \lor \lnot q$

this is my solution . Check it please

[image]

Comment: Your solution seems to be right!

Comment: You showed that if one of them is true that the other is true. What happens if one of them is false? You should show that if $\sim(p\wedge q) = F$, then $\sim p\vee \sim q = F$ as well. Additionally, you misspelled "true" and "truth" throughout (though I'm guessing you have mild dyslexia?).

Comment: so, you mean my solution above is true, and I need to show the false case.

Comment: plz plz plz. tell me if the solution above is enough or not

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is right apart from the second line in $(\Leftarrow)$: it should be

> $p$ $\color{red}{\text{ and }} q$ is false. Then $(p\land q)$ is false.$\ldots$

Comment: I think we can not say p and q are false. and it is okay to p or q are false.

Comment: I mean my solution is correct.

Comment: plz plz look at it

Comment: You write that $(\lnot p \lor \lnot q)$ is true. So $\lnot p$ is true, or $\lnot q$ is true, or both. That means $p$ is false, or $q$ is false, or both are false. In either case, that means that $p \land q$ must be false.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is right and covers all cases that arise in classical logic. Classically, a formula is false (in a model) if and only if it is not true (in the model). So, the falsity case mentioned in a comment reduces to showing that: If $\neg(p \wedge q)$ is not true, then $\neg p \vee \neg q$ is not true. But this is equivalent to a case you' ve already shown.

@Newb: The second line in $(\Leftarrow)$ is correct, since the falsity of a conjunct suffices to make the conjunction false.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is right but needs a few adjustments.
In the second line of $(\Rightarrow)$ it should be "is" not "are" in both cases.
Showing that "$p$ is true exactly when $q$ is true" is not enough to guarantee that $p$ and $q$ are equivalent, do you know why ?